# SharePoint REST API Get total available record count

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Can we get total number of available records in SharePoint 2013 site using REST API and Query Language FQL.

I did checked http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

But was not able to get Count of available records.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint REST Search API does not expose any specific parameter to return total results count, but contains `query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.TotalRows` value in response.

The following example demonstrates how to return the total results count:

```
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='news'&rowlimit=100",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.TotalRows); //get total results count
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
});
```